# How to run https with a porkbun SSL certificate in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

I tried to run a Node https server with the SSL certificate issued by porkbun, but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmZ8I.png)

Download the SSL certificate like above and install the

```js
import express from "express";
import path from 'path';
import fs from "fs";
import https from "https";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());;
app.use(cors());
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('/', (req:any, res:any) => {
    res.redirect('./build/index.html');
});

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("./ssl/private.key.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./ssl/domain.cert.pem"),
    ca: fs.readFileSync("./ssl/intermediate.cert.pem")
};

const createSecureServer = (app: express.Express, port: number) => {
  const secureServer = https.createServer(options, app);

  secureServer.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`HTTPS server started on port ${port}`);
  });
};
createSecureServer(app, 443);
```

When you run the server with the above code, you will see the message 'HTTPS server started on port 443' and the server will run on port 443

The problem is that when I go to the connected domain, I get a message that the value has not been sent from the server, which seems to say that the connection is working but the value has not been sent.

I'm thinking it might be a domain or some other setting issue, so if I run it with http instead of https, it shows the 'index.html' page with no problem, so which part is the problem?

I've never used https before so I don't know what the problem is.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy0Cp.png)

When I run curl in the terminal, it says it returns html with no problems.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKd3h.png)

However, when I go to the domain, I get the error "Page not working.No data sent from nanonix.lol.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" error is output.